# How to get list of user givenname property from an LDAP search for a group?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, tivoli

I am trying to fetch a list of users (user fullnames) belong to TEST group.
The search query I am using is

```
NamingEnumeration<?> enumeration = ldapCtx.search("ou=staff,o=filenet,dc=test,dc=com", "(cn=TEST_GROUP)", searchCtls);
```

It returns the group with uniquemembers list containing dn of all users. How do I fetch the fullname for these users ?

Note: I am using Tivoli Directory service. But a generic answer is fine.

Comment: The DN *is* the full name. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want the given name property of a user. Not the DN.

Comment: Doesn't say so in your question. Clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fetch all member's group fullnames in one LDAP request because there's no joins in LDAP. You should load members data individually from their DN to get fullnames.